# Bandwidth consideration of using AWS hardware VPN or Direct Connect?

Tags: vpn, bandwidth, amazon-vpc, bgp

I understand that aws hardware vpn has bandwidth limit of 4Gbps from https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

'You can also use AWS Direct Connect instead of establishing a VPN connection over the Internet to your Amazon VPC, avoiding the need to utilize VPN hardware that frequently can’t support data transfer rates above 4 Gbps.'

If my bandwidth requirement is under 4Gbps, and if the latency requirement of my application is not very sensitive, (also, let's not consider cost in this question) can my hardware vpn route (over public internet) provide a route of 4Gbps?

Note: I will do the cost analysis separately. But this question is more for bandwidth factor of a public route and a private circuit.

do I have a reason to use Direct Connect?

Answer (score 1):

Direct Connect should be first choice in case of high bandwidth requirement irrespective of the latency measurement because VPN setup indeed dependent on the public infrastructure used and may not be a best approach for a 4GB link connection. Whereas AWS Direct Connect will provide a seamless connectivity with guaranteed throughput. Again its up-to the application need to finalize the required setup.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your firewall and internet connection. On most enterprise level isp connections there is enough connection stability to host a vpn with no issue. That being said a run of the mill Comcast connection will have issues over time. Remember you can also be limited by your firewall's vpn throughput and capacity. You need a decently beefy firewall to achieve 4gbps through a vpn.

My guess is with the right equipment Direct Connect isn't necessary.